# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/DEREncodable during PDF Encryption

Tags: java, pdf, encryption, jasper-reports

Which JAR am I supposed to include in the class path to get rid of this error message?

```
Error exporting print... org/bouncycastle/asn1/DEREncodable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/DEREncodable
```

I am using :

**Product Version**: *Jaspersoft iReport Designer 5.0.1*

**Java**: *1.7.0.11; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 23.6-b04*

Comment: Does jasperreport 5 build on iText for PDF creation? If yes, which version? You'll need bouncycastle 1.46, 1.47, or 1.48.

Comment: hi,
Ireport 5.0.1 is using iText-2.1.7.js1.jar for pdf writing (I found out).
The corresponding bouncycastle jar is bcprov-jdk14-140.jar.
I downloaded it and added to classpath.
But no use.
Still the same error.
--------------
Exporting PDF (using iText) to file... C:\Users\NOMOS\Desktop\report1.pdf!
Error exporting print... org/bouncycastle/asn1/DEREncodable 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/DEREncodable      at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfEncryption.<init>(Unknown Source)      at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.setEncryption(Unknown Source)